# python merge json's dict's created in differnet sources to 1 dict json

Tags: python, json

This is the only an example but for the general idea :
i have Json as dict created in different places in the application
and in the end i like to merge them as 1 JSON .

```
json_1 ={}
formated_db_name = "formatedname"
json_1[formated_db_name] = {"data_source_name": formated_db_name}
json_1[formated_db_name] = {"db_servers_entry_list": {}}

json_2 = {}
formated_db_name2 = "formatedname2"
json_2[formated_db_name2] = {"data_source_name2": formated_db_name2}
json_2[formated_db_name2] = {"db_servers_entry_list2": {}}
```

it creates 2 jsons :

```
{
        "formatedname2": {
            "db_servers_entry_list2": {}
        }
}
```

and

```
 {
            "formatedname": {
                "db_servers_entry_list": {}
            }
   }
```

now i like to combine them to look like this :

```
{
    "formatedname2": {
        "db_servers_entry_list2": {}
    },
    "formatedname1": {
        "db_servers_entry_list1": {}
    }
}
```

didn't found any json.dumps method to combine both . ( there can be more then 2 such dict that i need to combine )

Comment: Do you want to merge the python dictionaries that you created or do you want to merge the json strings? Both are different.

Comment: if it can be in the python dictionaries level and then to just JSON.dumps on it 
will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate through the sequence of the dictionaries and call `update` and pass the individual dictionaries to a dictionary variable:

```py
out = {}
for each in (json_1, json_2):
    out.update(each)
    
# out
{'formatedname': {'db_servers_entry_list': {}}, 'formatedname2': {'db_servers_entry_list2': {}}}
```

You can later call `json.dumps` and pass `out` once you are done merging the dictionaries.
Since the dictionary is being update via the call to `update` method, it will maintain the the dictionary/json property (there is never going to be multiple key value pair for a single key, it will just update the dictionary with the latest value being passed for a key.)

Answer (score 1):

You can join the dicts beforehand and then you can use the dumps method!

```py
a = dict(a="Test")
b = dict(b=True)

c = dict()
c.update(a)
c.update(b)

print(c)
```

```
{
    "a": "Test",
    "b": True
}
```